# Do you use the plural "-j" when the quantity is zero ("nul"/0)?

Tags: plurals

For the sentence *I have 0 votes*, which one of these sentences should I say?

> Mi havas 0 voĉdonon.

> Mi havas 0 voĉdonojn.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/unu-nombro_multe-nombro/uzado/specialaj_okazoj.html#i-ds4), it is equally correct to either:

- Use the plural ending only for numbers greater than 1 (i.e. use the singular for both 0 and fractions less than 1)
- Use the plural ending for everything other than exactly 1 (this is what we do in English e.g. "I bought 0.5 pound**s** of something")

You just have to pick one and stick to it (also note that negative numbers should use the same form as their positive counterpart).

Usually, however, in everyday speech people use *neniu* instead of *nul*, so that often sounds more natural: *Mi havas neniun voĉdonon.* ([See PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/vortetoj/uzado.html#j-j14).)

Answer (score 3):

As a native English speaker, zero is the removal of the possibility of the quantity being 1, and so it seems to make sense that it's treated as a plural. However, as far as I know, this is not how it's treated in French and some other languages.

While either will be tendencies of native speakers of different mother languages, perhaps saying:

> Mi ne havas voĉdonon.

would be clearer, and avoid any assumption that `0` is a mistake because of the plural ending.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the interpretation that singular always refers to exactly one (or minus one, negative one). But there are other authoritative interpretations, as Chives said, and you can use either singular or plural.

But *voĉdono* means *voting*. I suppose you want to say

*Mi havas nul voĉojn*

I would use *nul* only in contexts with other numbers, like

*Karlo ricevis tridek voĉojn, Marta ok kaj mi nul voĉojn.*

Answer (score 0):

According to Unicode CLDR for [language plural rules](https://unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#eo), Esperanto uses singular for only exactly 1 (and -1). Any other value such as 0 or 0,5 would therefore use plural.

Comment: In the linked page, before all the rules are listed, it says "When you find errors or omissions in this data, please report the information with a bug report". Doesn't this mean that CLDR is not a good authority on this matter?

Comment: @svendvn Your logic is flawed. If someone accept error reports and is willing to correct it, that data should have a higher likelihood to be correct. Someone who refuses to change and won't accept input, will have errors that won't be corrected, and have a higher likelihood to be wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Ĉu ne, mi havas nenion da voĉdonoj? -> mi havas nul da voĉdonoj?

Comment: Ne, tiel oni ne povas diri. Devas esti _neniom da voĉoj_, _neniun voĉon_ aŭ _nul voĉo(j)n_. Oni neniam uzas _da_ post la senfinaĵaj nombrovortoj: _unu voĉon, dek voĉojn_ (sed neniam "dek da voĉoj"). Teorie eblas _nulo da voĉo(j)_, kaj oni trovas iom da tiaj uzoj.