# Ĉu pluralo post "nul"?

Tags: plurals

Kiun formon oni devus uzi?

```
0 frazo aldonita
```

aŭ

```
0 frazoj aldonitaj
```

Laŭ la [reguloj pri pluraloj de Unicode](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#eo) Esperanto havas singularan formon por 1, kaj pluralan por ĉiuj aliaj kvantoj (do ankaŭ por 0).

```
1 frazo
0,2,3,4,5,... frazoj
```

Sed laŭ mi devus esti:

```
0 frazo
1 frazo
2,3,4,5,... frazoj
```

En Tekstaro aperas ambaŭ, sed mi ŝatus scii ĉu ekzistas normo.

Comment: Vidu ankaŭ la jenan demandon kiu estas la sama sed en esperanto https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/do-you-use-the-plural-j-when-the-quantity-is-zero-nul-0?rq=1

Comment: Dankon, mi ne estis vidinta ĝin. Mi tamen ne tro scias kion fari kun la reguloj de CLDR. La demando estiĝis ĉar en Mozilla iu demandis kial mi aldonis tradukon por "0" se tio ne ekzistas aparte. Por ili la normo estas kompreneble CLDR ...

Comment: @NeilRoberts if you want to flag it as duplicate, go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laŭ [PMEG 8.2.4. Nombro – specialaj okazoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/unu-nombro_multe-nombro/uzado/specialaj_okazoj.html) ambaŭ eblas.

> #### [*Nul* kaj malpli](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/unu-nombro_multe-nombro/uzado/specialaj_okazoj.html#i-ds4)
>
> Kiam [***nul***](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/vortetoj/formoj.html#i-2i7) estas uzata kiel [**nombra priskribo**](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/vortetoj/uzado.html#j-j14), oni povas heziti, ĉu uzi unu-nombron aŭ multe-nombron, ĉar *nul* estas nek unu, nek pluraj. Oficiala regulo ne ekzistas. Oni povas rezoni en du manieroj:
>
> - Aŭ oni uzas J nur por nombroj super unu, do ne por ekz. nul aŭ 0,5.
> - Aŭ oni uzas J por ĉiuj (pozitivaj) nombroj krom ekzakte unu, do ankaŭ por nul kaj por nombroj inter nul kaj unu, ekz. 0,5.
>
> Ambaŭ aliroj estas egale logikaj:
>
> - *Post tio restos **nul homo(j)**.* Ĉi tia uzado de *nul* aperas preskaŭ nur en poezio k.s. Normale oni dirus *neniu homo* (aŭ *neniuj homoj*).
> - *Mi aĉetis **nul komo kvin kilogramo(j)n** da rizo.*
>
> […]

Comment: Aldone: tamen _Mi aĉetis duonan kilogramon da rizo._ Krome - ne devige - sed: _Nul homoj vizitis la restoracion._ kaj _Nul homo vizitis la necesejon._

Comment: Pardonu, mi ne komprenas vian komenton, @JoopEggen.

Comment: _duona_ + singularo estas klara. Pri la ceteraj kazoj: jes, tre malforta argumento mia: necesejo po unu persono, restoracio po pluraj.